# java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #11 bootstrap method

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to do an facial detection app applying the concepts available on [Firebase][1]
, but I'm getting the error  java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #11 .
bootstrap method

I already check all the depencies and they seems to be correct according to the website.
[1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces#kotlin+ktx_1

- My **build.gradle** is:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
 buildscript {
     ext {
          version_kotlin = "1.3.72"
          version_core = "1.3.1"
          version_constraint_layout = "2.0.0-rc1"
          version_lifecycle_extensions = "2.2.0"
          version_material = "1.2.0"
          version_navigation = "2.3.0"
      }
     repositories {
          google()
          mavenCentral()
      }
     dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
          classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$version_kotlin"
          classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$version_navigation"
          classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
       }
     }

      allprojects {

        repositories {
           google()
           mavenCentral()
      }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
      }
```

My **build.gradle (app level)** is :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

    apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


     android {
         compileSdkVersion 30
         buildFeatures {
         dataBinding true
      }
     defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android.myapplication'
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
      }
    buildTypes {
       release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
  productFlavors {
   }
  }

  dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$version_kotlin"

   // Constraint Layout
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$version_constraint_layout"

   // Core
   implementation "androidx.core:core:$version_core"

   // Material Design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$version_material"

   // Navigation
   implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$version_navigation"
   implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$version_navigation"


   //Camera
   def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha05"
   implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
   implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"


   //Firebase

   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.2')
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:20.0.1'
  }
```

I added the file FaceDetectionActivity.kt in my projet:

```
package com.example.android.myproject
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.*
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.view.View
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImageMetadata
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFace
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceContour
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark

class FaceDetectionActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FrameProcessor {
private var cameraFacing: Facing = Facing.FRONT

//private val imageView by lazy { findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.face_detection_image_view)!! }

/* private val bottomSheetButton by lazy { findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.bottom_sheet_button)!! }
 private val bottomSheetRecyclerView by lazy { findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.bottom_sheet_recycler_view)!! }
 private val bottomSheetBehavior by lazy { BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet)!!) }*/

var faceDetectionModels = ArrayList<FaceDetectionModel>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_halfface)
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    // supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    /*face_detection_camera_view.facing = cameraFacing
    face_detection_camera_view.setLifecycleOwner(this)
    face_detection_camera_view.addFrameProcessor(this)
    face_detection_camera_toggle_button.setOnClickListener {
        cameraFacing = if (cameraFacing == Facing.FRONT) Facing.BACK else Facing.FRONT
        face_detection_camera_view.facing = cameraFacing
    }*/

    /*bottomSheetButton.setOnClickListener {
        CropImage.activity().start(this)
    }*/

    /*bottomSheetRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    bottomSheetRecyclerView.adapter = FaceDetectionAdapter(this, faceDetectionModels)*/
}

override fun process(frame: Frame) {

    val width = frame.size.width
    val height = frame.size.height

    val metadata = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
        .setWidth(width)
        .setHeight(height)
        .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
        .setRotation(if (cameraFacing == Facing.FRONT) FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_270 else FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_90)
        .build()

    val firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(frame.data, metadata)
    val options = FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
        .setContourMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CONTOURS)
        .build()
    val faceDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(options)
    faceDetector.detectInImage(firebaseVisionImage)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            //image
            //face_detection_camera_image_view.setImageBitmap(null)

            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(height, width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            val dotPaint = Paint()
            dotPaint.color = Color.RED
            dotPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
            dotPaint.strokeWidth = 4F
            val linePaint = Paint()
            linePaint.color = Color.GREEN
            linePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            linePaint.strokeWidth = 2F

            for (face in it) {

                val faceContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.FACE).points
                for ((i, contour) in faceContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != faceContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, faceContours[i + 1].x, faceContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    else
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, faceContours[0].x, faceContours[0].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val leftEyebrowTopContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.LEFT_EYEBROW_TOP).points
                for ((i, contour) in leftEyebrowTopContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != leftEyebrowTopContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, leftEyebrowTopContours[i + 1].x, leftEyebrowTopContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val leftEyebrowBottomContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.LEFT_EYEBROW_BOTTOM).points
                for ((i, contour) in leftEyebrowBottomContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != leftEyebrowBottomContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, leftEyebrowBottomContours[i + 1].x, leftEyebrowBottomContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val rightEyebrowTopContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.RIGHT_EYEBROW_TOP).points
                for ((i, contour) in rightEyebrowTopContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != rightEyebrowTopContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, rightEyebrowTopContours[i + 1].x, rightEyebrowTopContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val rightEyebrowBottomContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.RIGHT_EYEBROW_BOTTOM).points
                for ((i, contour) in rightEyebrowBottomContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != rightEyebrowBottomContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, rightEyebrowBottomContours[i + 1].x, rightEyebrowBottomContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val leftEyeContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.LEFT_EYE).points
                for ((i, contour) in leftEyeContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != leftEyeContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, leftEyeContours[i + 1].x, leftEyeContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    else
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, leftEyeContours[0].x, leftEyeContours[0].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val rightEyeContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.RIGHT_EYE).points
                for ((i, contour) in rightEyeContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != rightEyeContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, rightEyeContours[i + 1].x, rightEyeContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    else
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, rightEyeContours[0].x, rightEyeContours[0].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val upperLipTopContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.UPPER_LIP_TOP).points
                for ((i, contour) in upperLipTopContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != upperLipTopContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, upperLipTopContours[i + 1].x, upperLipTopContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val upperLipBottomContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.UPPER_LIP_BOTTOM).points
                for ((i, contour) in upperLipBottomContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != upperLipBottomContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, upperLipBottomContours[i + 1].x, upperLipBottomContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val lowerLipTopContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.LOWER_LIP_TOP).points
                for ((i, contour) in lowerLipTopContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != lowerLipTopContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, lowerLipTopContours[i + 1].x, lowerLipTopContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val lowerLipBottomContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.LOWER_LIP_BOTTOM).points
                for ((i, contour) in lowerLipBottomContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != lowerLipBottomContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, lowerLipBottomContours[i + 1].x, lowerLipBottomContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val noseBridgeContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.NOSE_BRIDGE).points
                for ((i, contour) in noseBridgeContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != noseBridgeContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, noseBridgeContours[i + 1].x, noseBridgeContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }

                val noseBottomContours = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.NOSE_BOTTOM).points
                for ((i, contour) in noseBottomContours.withIndex()) {
                    if (i != noseBottomContours.lastIndex)
                        canvas.drawLine(contour.x, contour.y, noseBottomContours[i + 1].x, noseBottomContours[i + 1].y, linePaint)
                    canvas.drawCircle(contour.x, contour.y, 4F, dotPaint)
                }


                if (cameraFacing == Facing.FRONT) {
                    val matrix = Matrix()
                    matrix.preScale(-1F, 1F)
                    val flippedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, matrix, true)
                    //face_detection_camera_image_view.setImageBitmap(flippedBitmap)
                } else {
                    //face_detection_camera_image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }
            }

        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            // face_detection_camera_image_view.setImageBitmap(null)
        }
}

public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // val imageUri = result.uri
        //analyzeImage(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri))
        print("Ok")
        //image
        //face_detection_camera_container.visibility = View.GONE
       }
     } 
  } 
private fun analyzeImage(image: Bitmap?) {
  if (image == null) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "There was some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    //return
    print("There was some error")
}

//image

// imageView.setImageBitmap(null)
//faceDetectionModels.clear()
//bottomSheetRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
//bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
// showProgress()

val firebaseVisionImage = image?.let { FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(it) }
val options = FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
    .setPerformanceMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE)
    .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
    .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
    .build()
val faceDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(options)
if (firebaseVisionImage != null) {
    faceDetector.detectInImage(firebaseVisionImage)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            val mutableImage = image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)

            detectFaces(it, mutableImage)

            //image
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableImage)
            //hideProgress()
            /*bottomSheetRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED*/
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "There was some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            print("Error")
            //hideProgress()
        }
     }
 }

  private fun detectFaces(faces: List<FirebaseVisionFace>?, image: Bitmap?) {
     if (faces == null || image == null) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "There was some error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    //return
    print("Error")
}

val canvas = image?.let { Canvas(it) }
val facePaint = Paint()
facePaint.color = Color.RED
facePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
facePaint.strokeWidth = 8F
val faceTextPaint = Paint()
faceTextPaint.color = Color.RED
faceTextPaint.textSize = 40F
faceTextPaint.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
val landmarkPaint = Paint()
landmarkPaint.color = Color.RED
landmarkPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
landmarkPaint.strokeWidth = 8F

if (faces != null) {
    for ((index, face) in faces.withIndex()) {

        if (canvas != null) {
            canvas.drawRect(face.boundingBox, facePaint)
        }
        canvas?.drawText("Face$index", (face.boundingBox.centerX() - face.boundingBox.width() / 2) + 8F, (face.boundingBox.centerY() + face.boundingBox.height() / 2) - 8F, faceTextPaint)

        if (face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE) != null) {
            val leftEye = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EYE)!!
            canvas?.drawCircle(leftEye.position.x, leftEye.position.y, 8F, landmarkPaint)
        }
        if (face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE) != null) {
            val rightEye = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EYE)!!
            canvas?.drawCircle(rightEye.position.x, rightEye.position.y, 8F, landmarkPaint)
        }
        if (face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.NOSE_BASE) != null) {
            val nose = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.NOSE_BASE)!!
            canvas?.drawCircle(nose.position.x, nose.position.y, 8F, landmarkPaint)
        }
        if (face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR) != null) {
            val leftEar = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.LEFT_EAR)!!
            canvas?.drawCircle(leftEar.position.x, leftEar.position.y, 8F, landmarkPaint)
        }
        if (face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EAR) != null) {
            val rightEar = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.RIGHT_EAR)!!
            canvas?.drawCircle(rightEar.position.x, rightEar.position.y, 8F, landmarkPaint)
        }
        if (face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.MOUTH_LEFT) != null && face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.MOUTH_BOTTOM) != null && face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.MOUTH_RIGHT) != null) {
            val leftMouth = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.MOUTH_LEFT)!!
            val bottomMouth = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.MOUTH_BOTTOM)!!
            val rightMouth = face.getLandmark(FirebaseVisionFaceLandmark.MOUTH_RIGHT)!!
            canvas?.drawLine(leftMouth.position.x, leftMouth.position.y, bottomMouth.position.x, bottomMouth.position.y, landmarkPaint)
            canvas?.drawLine(bottomMouth.position.x, bottomMouth.position.y, rightMouth.position.x, rightMouth.position.y, landmarkPaint)
        }

        /*faceDetectionModels.add(FaceDetectionModel(index, "Smiling Probability  ${face.smilingProbability}"))
        faceDetectionModels.add(FaceDetectionModel(index, "Left Eye Open Probability  ${face.leftEyeOpenProbability}"))
        faceDetectionModels.add(FaceDetectionModel(index, "Right Eye Open Probability  ${face.rightEyeOpenProbability}"))*/
          }
      }
  }
```

I don't undestand what is the problem...

**My goal is to run a face detector in real time in Android with Kotlin language**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is necessary to add the following configuration in **build.Gradle (app level)**:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```